# What is the equipment level range from drops at Inferno Difficulty?

Tags: diablo-iii

Are the drops all level 60? Do they vary between acts like at other difficulty levels?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Level 61/63 Drop Rates after Diablo 3 Patch 1.03

After patch 1.03 the item level drops at Inferno difficulty have been changed. High-end items (items level 61-63) will now drop in all Acts of Inferno and Acts III and IV of Hell difficulty. The new approximate drop rates are the followings:

```
Hell - Act III and Act IV
iLvl 61: 13.9% (+4.9%)*
iLvl 62: 3.45% (+1.55%)*
iLvl 63: 0% (no change)*

Inferno - Act I
iLvl 61: 23.9% (+6.2%)*
iLvl 62: 12.6% (+4.7%)*
iLvl 63: 4.8% (+2.8%)*

Inferno - Act II
iLvl 61: 23.3% (+4.7%)*
iLvl 62: 18.6% (+6.2%)* 
iLvl 63: 9.3% (+5.2%)*

Inferno - Act III and Act IV
iLvl 61: 27.1% (+3.0%)*
iLvl 62: 21.7% (+5.6%)*
iLvl 63: 16.3% (+8.3%)*
```

**[*] show the increment from 1.03 to 1.03b patch**

#### Patch 1.02 and previous (history)

Before Diablo 3 patch 1.03 the item level drops at Inferno difficulty were the following:

- Inferno Act I: You had a chance to get an item level 61* drop or inferior.
- Inferno Act II: You had a chance to get an item level 62* drop or inferior.
- Inferno Act III/IV: You had a chance to get an item level 63* drop or inferior.

*The item tooltip will show level 60 in any case.

Comment: Nice! But do you have a source for that quote?

Comment: Temporary I can indicated this reddit as source (http://www.reddit.com/r/Diablo/comments/v9x98/official_103_patch_notes/) later on I will update my answer with link to official Blizzard changelog. Same % values has been twitted by @Bashiok (Blizzard Community Manager) some days ago.

Comment: Thanks! I've found that http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/69881/2634 mentioned this link: http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/6262208/ . Nothing beats official patch notes, though.

Answer (score 2):

Hell Act 4 drops mostly gear sub-level 60 and so does Inferno Act 1. I'm not far into Inferno yet, but already now I can (almost) safely say that it varies like on other difficulty levels, beacause only some of the items I find are level 60, definitely not all.

Comment: What is the lowest level gear you've found on inferno so far?

Answer (score 2):

Jay Wilson stated in this Inferno [Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0o9kgd6S0lU), that every Act in Inferno increases in difficulty and loot quality. But not all drops are level 60.